# couldn't make Android ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this) to work

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I added this to MyApplication .create() method

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), PARSE_APP_ID,PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
```

Error:(30, 39) error: incompatible types: MyApplication cannot be converted to String ! initialize function take Context as a parameter so why it's not working ?!!!

```
public static void initialize(android.content.Context context) { /* compiled code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of hours i found the answer and thanks to [This github project](https://github.com/thespianartist/FacebookLoginInAndroidUsingParse)

First i updated Android Studio and updated the gradle to 1.1.2

Second made the dependences like follows 
[image: Didn't add the parse Facebook utils]

Third added this ext to the Project gradle file

```
ext {

facebookSDK = 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
androidSupport = 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
bolts = 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
parsePath = "$rootProject.projectDir/app/libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar"
parseFacebookUtilsPath = "$rootProject.projectDir/app/libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar"
```

}

Forth updated the module gradle file to be like that

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
compile files(rootProject.ext.parsePath)
compile files(rootProject.ext.parseFacebookUtilsPath)
```

}

it didn't work when i added it normally at the dependences but now it's working and project can be build normally.